# DOM demorando para responder

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Seguinte, tenho uma aplicação que dentro do .NET o carregamento é rápido, demora 1.423s para o método responder, só que quando vai para a VIEW está demorando mais...

é como se algo estivesse segurando a liberação da tela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Quantidade de registros retornados por método:**

- "listarMotoristas" : 14
- "listarCaminhoes" : 16
- "listarTransportadoras" : 77
- "listarEstabelecimento" : 6
- "listarColetasPendentes" : 278
- "listarOrdensEmConferencia" : 308

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código que utilizo na VIEW :**

https://paste.ofcode.org/4Uf4PZUndm8f6L3NLyh9cv

Existe algo que esteja fazendo de errado ou que eu possa melhorar?

Obrigado.

Comment: Uma primeira pergunta é, para cada chamada dessas, quantos itens são retornados? Para algumas chamadas você criar vários elementos antes de fazer o `append`, precisa ver a quantidade para entender o problema de performance

Comment: Fala Ricardo, acabei de atualizar o post.

Comment: Não é muita coisa pra causar essa lentidão, o problema deve ser na forma como está adicionando os elementos.. antes de postar uma resposta, façamos um teste com um serviço qualquer, o "ListarColetaPendente" por exemplo. No seu código, você adiciona os elementos dentro do `each`, o que é ruim, pois o `DOM` tem de ser processado muitas vezes... vamos criar um elemento qualquer, um `div`, adicionar todos os elementos a esse `div` dentro do `each` e finalmente adicionar tudo de uma vez ao `DOM` para ver se isso já resolve (senão teremos que fazer sem `jQuery`)

Comment: Mais fácil, vamos usar "ListarLotesEmAndamento"
na linha 225, antes do each, você vai criar um elemento> `var $d = $("<div />");`, e na linha 283, você não vai adicionar mais o conteúdo "myWellLote" na "divColetar", mas assim:  `$d.append(myWellLote)`; Por fim, adicione $d fora do foreach, lá na linha 294: `$('#divColetar').append($d);`

Comment: Isso vai fazer você processar todas as divs novas dentro de um elemento sem adicionar ao `DOM`, adicionando tudo no final, o que deixa bem mais rápido. Faça um teste para ver a diferença

Comment: Muito mais rápido, só a o método ListarColetaPendente que está segurando agora...

Comment: O problema no método ListarColetaPendente é que este If serve para agrupar as informações por Região.. ou seja, adicionar as ordens dentro da div da região...

Comment: Verdade, por isso, desisti dele como exemplo :)  mas vamos tentar fazer sem o jQuery, já vai ajudar

Comment: No `each` lá na linha 180, vamos criar um elemento e adicionar o conteúdo: `var e = document.createElement("div"); e.innerHTML = myWellLogistica`;  e mudar para `document.getElementById('divPendenciasLogistica').appendChild(e);` e fazer o mesmo com "myOrdem"

Comment: Veja se usando javascript puro melhora a performance

Comment: Acho que neste caso compensa modificar a forma como é montado isso no .NET para fazer igual ao método ListarLotesEmAndamento.. .aí consigo eliminar este if.

O que acha?

Comment: Isso seria o ideal se você puder fazer, ai pode fazer como nos outros, adicionar o conteúdo dinâmico num elemento que não está no `dom` e depois adicionar tudo de uma vez. Se de curiosidade, quanto melhorou o tempo de algum deles pra ter uma ideia?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80864/discussion-between-anderson-apdo-de-souza-and-ricardo-pontual).

Comment: Olha só os tempos... https://ibb.co/cPm8to